# Mesh appears with holes

Tags: java, opengl, mesh, normals, jmonkeyengine

Is it possible to say by eye, what is wrong with the following mesh:

[image]

I am sure, that triangle structure is good initially:

[image]

But error is probably on the stage of preparing mesh for jME3.

Probably I flip some triangles, because it looks reverse from behind:

[image]

How to control triangle orientation?

I form list of vertex index in straight way

```
List<Mesh.Triangle> triangles = mesh.calculateTriangles2();
    indexes = new int[triangles.size()*3];
    int ii;
    for(int i=0; i<triangles.size(); ++i) {
        ii = 0;
        for(Mesh.Node node : triangles.get(i)) {
            indexes[i*3+ii] = nodesMap.get(node);
            ii++;
        }
    }
```

which leads the order of vertices in triangles are random. What defines orientation?

Comment: I think you might be calculating the normals incorrectly, assuming you are doing so manually. If you use the vector product on two edges you may get a normal vector that points either up or down, depending on which edges you choose.

Comment: either bad normals or bad winding

Comment: The winding @ratchetfreak mentioned is that OpenGL by default considers counter-clockwise vertex order as a definition of the front face of a polygon. If you accidentally draw the vertices in clockwise order, they will face the other direction.

Comment: Do a glPolygonMode(GL_LINE) and check if the triangles are drawn properly. If so do disable face culling. This should solve your issue I think.

Comment: Are you trying to draw this as a triangle strip by chance? That is what the end result looks like to me. Without seeing the actual drawing code, that is just a guess, however.